# a simple performSegue throws and error in prepare for segue func

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

Maybe something silly, but I am trying to simply move from a tableviewController to a viewController not passing any data just a simple move using

```
@IBAction func requestPanel(_ sender: Any) {

   performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendMail", sender: AnyObject)
}
```

And then I get an error in a prepare for segue func.

But what does that have to no with my other segue?

I understand that that segue will have trouble since there is no data.

As you see here segue is above prepare for segue.

```
@IBAction func requestPanel(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendMail", sender: AnyObject.self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var indexPath: IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let desti = segue.destination as! DeviceDetailTableViewController

    let selectedRecord = onlineDevices[indexPath.row]

    let panelWidth = selectedRecord.object(forKey: "panelwidth") as? String
    let panelHight = selectedRecord.object(forKey: "panelhight") as? String
    let panelPitch = selectedRecord.object(forKey: "panelpitch") as? String
    let panelPower = selectedRecord.object(forKey: "panelpower") as? String
    let panelWeight = selectedRecord.object(forKey: "panelweight") as? String
    let panelMaker = selectedRecord.object(forKey: "maker") as? String
    let panelModel = selectedRecord.object(forKey: "model") as?      String

    desti.pawidth = panelWidth!
    desti.pahight = panelHight!
    desti.papitch = panelPitch!
    desti.papower = panelPower!
    desti.weight = panelWeight!
    desti.maker = panelMaker!
    desti.model = panelModel!
}



 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 return 1
 }
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return onlineDevices.count
 }
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DeviceCell", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    let noteRecord: CKRecord = onlineDevices[(indexPath as IndexPath).row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = noteRecord.value(forKey: "maker") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = noteRecord.value(forKey: "model") as? String


    return cell
}


}
```

Comment: Whenever you call the perform segue method it’ll create a segue and the new view controller where you want to segue too. If that is done the system will call the prepare to give you the chance to pass data to the next view controller. Since you miss data here and Force unwrap it crashes when trying to segue.

Comment: Your segue is triggered from a button instead of from selecting a row, so check your segue identifier before trying to get the selected row.

Comment: DO _NOT_ show pictures of code. Show _CODE_.

Comment: @vacawama Yes the segue is triggere from a UIBarbutton, witch is correct since I do not want to bring any data.

Comment: @matt OK, here is the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All segues in a viewController will go through the same `prepare(for:sender:)` method.  You need to use the `segue.identifier` to handle the different segues differently.

Your `sendMail` segue comes from a `UIBarButton` action instead of from a selected row, so check for that segue and handle it separately:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "sendMail" {
        // nothing extra to be done here
    } else {
        // do your normal path here
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // you have a valid selected row so proceed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear. You are saying `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` at a time when no row is selected. Therefore that value is `nil`, and you crash when you force-unwrap it.

You wrote your original `prepareForSegue` when your only segue was triggered by the user selecting a row of the table. But *this* segue is *not* triggered by the user selecting a row of the table; it is triggered by the user tapping a button. You have to account for that difference.

(This is a major flaw in the whole architecture: all segues from a given view controller flow into the same `prepareForSegue`, which becomes a bottleneck.)

Comment: my table segue is working fine, just added another segue to an new VC and then got the problem.

Comment: Because you wrote your original `prepareForSegue` without understanding what it means or how it works?